# Jenkins-Pipline get amount of failed builds

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to make a notification system, that uses slack to notify. but to make it go to more than one channel when it gets worst to a few more. For this I need to see more than just the previous build that you can do like :

```
currentBuild.getPreviousBuild().result
```

But more in the lines of:

```
currentBuild.getAmountOfConsecutiveFaildAttemtpts()
```

So if I head a certain threshold I can push to more then one channel. Any idea Would be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`currentBuild.previousBuild` returns a [`RunWrapper`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html), which is the same exact object as `currentBuild`. This means you can traverse the builds in either direction by using [`getPreviousBuild()`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getPreviousBuild--) or [`getNextBuild()`](http://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-support/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/support/steps/build/RunWrapper.html#getNextBuild--).

Here is a rough, quick example. You will have to think about how parallel builds may affect your result. You could move this into a [*Shared Library*](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) if you want to reuse it across multiple pipelines:

```groovy
int failures = 0
def examinedBuild = currentBuild.previousBuild
while(examinedBuild != null) {
  echo "Build Number ${examinedBuild.number} -> ${examinedBuild.result}" 
  if (examinedBuild.result == 'FAILURE') {
    failures = failures + 1
  }
  examinedBuild = examinedBuild.previousBuild
}
```

Comment: I did not know that it was a runWrapperso this is exactly what I needed :).